# Regular expression to insert missing string?

Tags: regex

So I have this txt with a list of lines:
some lines contain this string aaa, some don't.
String is in between various strings, and separated with tab:

```
Randomstring1 aaa randomstring2
Randomstring3 randomstring4
Randomstring5 aaa randomstring6
```

I want to insert the string aaa in the lines that are missing the string aaa (between two various strings).

So the result be:

```
Randomstring1 aaa randomstring2
Randomstring3 aaa randomstring4
Randomstring5 aaa randomstring6
```

I can match lines not containing aaa with:

```
^(((?!aaa).)*)$
```

Tried to replace with $aaa, but no good result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to check whether the first word is followed by `aaa` or not.

Regex:

```
^(\S+\s+)(?!aaa\s+)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1aaa
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cX8uD8/6)